# Given the operation X$*$Y = $X^c \cap Y^c$ proof that G={P(A),$*$} it is not group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the set A={0,1,2,3,4} and the operation X$*$Y = $X^c \cap Y^c$ proof that G={P(A),$*$} it is not group

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! You have to use MathJax to render all the math expressions, and it is preferable to show us what have you tried so far, so we can help you better.

Comment: For reference, here's a simple MathJax tutorial (it's a lot easier than you might think; trust me): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! Could you tell us, please, what do you mean by $X^c$ and $Y^c$? Personally, I have not encountered such notation before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can't be an identity,  since for any $Z$, we have $X*Z=X^c\cap Z^c\subset X^c$, hence $X*Z\neq X$.

Comment: Thanks capo la verdad que sos un genio capo master y me salvaste la vida